# What does the black goddess statue do and what is it?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

In Hateno village, there is a boy you can talk to and he brings you to the statue. All I know is that it takes away a heart container. Does it do anything else and what does it represent?

Answer (score 23):

Based on your explanation, you are at the beginning stage of the quest [The Statue's Bargain](https://zelda.fandom.com/wiki/The_Statue%27s_Bargain). The statue steals either a heart container or stamina vessel, and the quest is regain whichever the statue took from you.

After you finish the quest, the [Horned Statue](https://zelda.fandom.com/wiki/Horned_Statue) will allow you to exchange heart containers for stamina vessels (and vice versa). This is designed to reallocate your stats as you see fit after already increasing them with spirit orbs.

Comment: What you put sounds correct but doesnt this happen outside of Hateno Village? The OP states they were near Kakariko, however they could be mistaken.

Comment: @KyleRone The OP is more likely mistaken. There is no such statue that does what they describe outside Hateno Village :) Plus, any Google searches inquiring "black statue" all point to Hateno Village